# Matching pairs of array

Tags: java

I have an array with integers, I just have to count the pairs and return that counted value.

```
static int StockMerchant(int n , int arr[]){
    int[] temp = new int[n];
    int count = 0;
    for(int i =0  ; i<n ; i++){
            for(int j= i+1 ; j<n ; j++){

                if(arr[i]==arr[j]){

                   arr[j] = '0';
                   arr[i] ='0';
                   count++;
                }
            }


    }
        return count;
}
```

when I try:                      `1 1 2 2 2`: gives output 2

But when I change the input to    `1 2 1 2 2`: gives output 3

I want the output to be 2 in the second case also. please help.

Comment: What exactly do you consider a "Matching Pair"? In my opinion your first output should be 4.

Comment: Yes elaborate the question please.

Comment: @DevilsHnd sry for my english . all i want to say that if an array having 2 similar elements then it said to be one pair.. and i have to count those pairs.

Comment: Setting pairs you've already found to zero is not the correct way to make sure you don't count them again.  It just happens to work in the first case. But in second case, you find 1s at positions 0 and 2 and set them to zero (count 1); then you find 2s at pos 1 and 3 and set them to zero (count 2).  Then you find **zeros** at positions 2 and 3 (count 3).

Answer (score 1):

*Sorry for my bad paint skills.

Hope I was able to point out your mistake:)

[image: Mistake]

Here is my solution :
Its basically sorting the array first and checking if it matches the value increment i position to j+1 and j as i+1

```
static int StockMerchant(int n, int arr[]) {
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    i = j + 1;
                    j = i;
                    count++;
                }
            }

        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Mark the answer right. If the solution is right. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Here i'm assuming all your test inputs contains positive integers, this logic works for the positive values only.

```
static int StockMerchant(int n , int arr[]){
            int starter = n>0 && arr[0] != 0 ? 0 : -1;
            int temp = starter;
            int count = 0;
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            for(int i =0  ; i<n ; i++){
                if(temp == arr[i]){
                    temp = starter;
                    count++;
                }else{
                    temp = arr[i];
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the help.. but i am not getting where i was wrong..